# Crash on __NSArrayM objectAtIndex but I did validation

Tags: ios, multithreading

I got this crash:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1838551b8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:165)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18228c55c objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18373071c -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 228 (NSArray.m:389)
3   living                          0x100c0d89c -[RequestCache sendEvents] + 76
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x1826de1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:455)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x1826eaf94 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576 (inline_internal.h:2424)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1826f7634 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204 (source.c:594)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1826e0160 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820 (source.c:897)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1826e2bbc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 572 (inline_internal.h:2461)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x183802810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1793)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1838003fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660 (CFRunLoop.c:3004)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18372e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
12  GraphicsServices                0x1851e2198 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
13  UIKit                           0x1897757fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684 (UIApplication.m:2650)
14  UIKit                           0x189770534 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4092)
15  living                          0x10065fb2c main + 88 (main.m:15)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x1827115b8 start + 4
```

Crash happens in following code:

```
NSMutableArray * cachedRequests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   // ....

- (void) sendEvents {

    if (cachedRequests != nil && [cachedRequests count] == 0){
        return;
    }
    MyCacheData *requestData = [cachedRequests objectAtIndex:0]; // <- Crash happens here

    if (requestData != nil) {
        [cachedRequests removeObject:requestData];
    }    
}
```

I call `sendEvents` from different places and different threads, for example as:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self sendEvents];
    });
```

or from callback of `NSURLSessionDataTask`

do I need to lock all method content with `@synchronized (self) {}`?

like:

```
- (void) sendEvents {
 @synchronized (self) {   
    if (cachedRequests != nil && [cachedRequests count] == 0){
        return;
    }
    MyCacheData *requestData = [cachedRequests objectAtIndex:0]; 

    if (requestData != nil) {
        [cachedRequests removeObject:requestData];
    }  
  }  
}
```

or there is other more suitable way to get rid of this crash?

---

I got this exception from iTunes Connect from version in Production

**[EDIT]**

when I try to set 0 length for `cachedRequests` and call `[cachedRequests objectAtIndex:0]` I get Exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
>   empty array'

However from my crash report I see:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 228 (NSArray.m:389)
```

Are both the same or problem happens because multithreading?

Comment: Is it need to call dispatch_time ? it will call on main thread without GCD api

Comment: @snaggs Looking at your edit I believe these are the same issue. You are emptying the array and accessing to reproduce the bug? You concurrency issue comes from checking the `count != 0`, then another thread removes the object from the array before your call to `objectAtIndex:`. So the same crash will arise in either case, you are just reproducing it synchronously.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen I just wonder there is no mention of `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`. ok ill except your answer

Comment: @snaggs As I understand it, the more verbose error you show above came from the console in Xcode, vs the shorter one that came from a crash report? If so, this is expected, you typically only get the additional debug info from the debugger, which is why it is so valuable to be able to reproduce an issue reliably in a test environment.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen thank you, makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution looks sensible, this does appear to be a concurrency issue.

Depending on what is happening in the rest of your class I would use the `cachedRequests` object as the token for synchronisation `@synchronized (cachedRequests)`. Depends if you have other things you want to sync with the same lock?

You will also want to add the same lock, with the same token, to any other code that is manipulating this array, to synchronise all access to it.

Comment: Do I need to do it out of method `sendEvents` or inside? If out - why?

Comment: I would do it where you have it inside the method, as this means that anytime you call that method you can be sure it is locked, otherwise you have to remember to do it each time.

Comment: Just to be clear, the most important thing is that you make sure you lock anywhere else that is manipulating that array too, to ensure that it cannot be changed between you check of the count and getting the value.

Comment: please take a look on my EDIT I posted

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your `sendEvents` method, create a copy of your array, thus:

```
NSArray *myCopiedArray = [cachedRequests copy];
```

Then, use this copy in your if statement and in your `objectAtIndex:`.

But still use the original array in the line `[cachedRequests removeObject:requestData];`.

That way, you're taking a snapshot of the array's current state, and using the exact same state for the `if` comparison and for retrieving an object.